# Why am I getting nil for tableview outlet?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

When the callback for the TaskListDataSource gets called it reloads both the todayVC and the reviewVC because they are UITableViewControllers. However the plannerVC is not and the tableview property is an outlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Why is it that when the callback runs it crashes saying it is nil. If I am somehow able to scroll across in the page view however and and view the plannerVC it will never crash as the tableview has been loaded into memory. But why doesn't it do it initially?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let taskListDataSource = TaskListDataSource {
            self.todayVC.tableView.reloadData()
            self.plannerVC.tableView.reloadData()
            self.reviewVC.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        todayVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TodayViewController", creator: { coder in
            return TodayViewController(coder: coder, taskListDataSource: taskListDataSource)
        })
        plannerVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PlannerViewController", creator: { coder in
            return PlannerViewController(coder: coder, taskListDataSource: taskListDataSource)
        }) 
        reviewVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ReviewViewController", creator: { coder in
            return ReviewViewController(coder: coder, taskListDataSource: taskListDataSource)
        })
        addVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AddViewController")
        setViewControllers([todayVC], direction: .forward, animated: false)
        dataSource = self
        print(plannerVC.tableView) // Console is printing nil
}
```

Comment: You're trying to access `self.plannerVC.tableView` within your initialization of `TaskListDataSource`, but your `plannerVC` is being set two statements *after* that.

Comment: Even after you fixed the "access order" stated by Alexander, you did instantiate them, but even if the IBOutlet has been correctly connected in the Storyboard, it hasn't been loaded yet. You might force its loading with `plannerVC.loadView()`

Comment: @Larme I read the documentation provided by apple regarding the `loadView()` function and the first line states `You should never call this method directly.` so I have called `loadViewIfNeeded()` instead and it has fixed the problem. It makes if wonder if this is the only solution for the problem I am facing.

Comment: Indeed, `loadViewIfNeeded()` instead of `loadView()`, my bad. For your issue, you are trying to access the `IBOutlet` of a ViewController which hasn't been loaded yet. Could you access the IBOutlet later, or do you need it now? That's the big question, it depend on your architecture...

Comment: @Larme I have a UIPageViewController that contains two UITableViewControllers (accessing the tableview from these is ok) and then I have a UIViewController with a tableview outlet. These all get initialised in the viewDidLoad function in the UIPageViewController. 

I have a closure defined in the UIPageController which essentially reloads all the tableviews when changes occur - this ensures all UI is in sync. But it crashes cause the tableview in the UIViewController is nil

Comment: Which one is called first? The closure or the `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @Larme `viewDidLoad()` is not being called on the plannerVC (the UIViewController that contains the tableview that is nil). When I called `plannerVC.loadViewIfNeeded()` it forces all outlets to be initialised therefor when the closure is called the tableview is not nil. I don't like the approach that I have done with `loadViewIfNeeded()` and feel as though I am missing something obvious or something that is an alternative to this `loadViewIfNeeded()` function. The closure is called in response to when the user taps a checkbox on a cell (Forces an update for all tableviews)

Comment: It depends. Could be that your closure is called too soon and shouldn't be. Could be that's calling on ALL VC when only one should in fact reload the tableView, since others haven't been loaded yet. So, I'd suggest you add a method (through a protocol maybe) on each of your VC: `func refreshData() { if isViewLoaded { self.tableView.reloadData() }}`, and in your closure: `self.plannerVC.refreshData()` Also, in that closure, I would have used a `[weak self]`, just in case (but then full check the memory cycle).

Comment: @Larme I ended adding to the closure `if self.plannerVC.isViewLoaded { self.plannerVC.tableView.reloadData()  }}`. Which satisfies everything that I wanted. merci beaucoup :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `instantiateInitialViewController(creator:)`, the `UIViewController` is initiated, but its `view` (and all subviews, including then all the `IBOutlet`) aren't loaded in memory.

So when, you try to do `self.someIBoutlet` (in your case `self.plannerVC.tableView.reloadData()`, it crashes.

A solution, would be to force the view to load, with `loadViewIfNeeded()`.
Since loading the view can be heavy, it's usually used when the ViewController will be shown shortly after (for instance, in a `didSet` of some property that access outlet in it, because it will be shown on screen in a few instants, so the view will be loaded anyway, just a few moment after).

Since you are loading 3 `UIViewController`, could it be that you aren't showing them, but prematurely loading them?
If that's the case, you might rethink your app architecture (all your `UIViewController` don't need to be initialized and in memory, and less to have their view loaded).
Still, you can check beforehand if the view has been loaded, and that you can access the outlets with `isViewLoaded`.

I'dd add for that a method in PlannerVC:

```
func refreshData() { 
    guard isViewLoaded else { return } 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Side note, it could be a protocol (and even more, complexe, like adding `var tableView { get set }`, and have a default implementation of `refreshData()`, but that's going further, not necessary)...

```
protocol Refreshable {
    func refreshData()
}
```

```
let taskListDataSource = TaskListDataSource {
    self.todayVC.refreshData()
    self.plannerVC.refreshData()
    self.reviewVC.refreshData()
}
```

Side note, I would check if there isn't memory retain cycles, I would have use a `[weak self]` in the closure of `TaskListDataSource`, and also would have made it a property of the VC.